# Traffic a specifc IP range using wireguard

Tags: networking, vpn, wireguard

I'm using wireguard and I'm trying to tunneling specfic ip range on VPN.

My scenario:

- 1 VPN server (wireguard);
- 1 Application server
- 4 Client servers

In client servers it's ok. All traffic is on wireguard. But, in Application server, I need that only specfic ip range (to communicate with client servers) uses the VPN. The rest of traffic out VPN (and receive internet connections like a ssh - out VPN).

I think that I need to add some router... Someone has a refference?

Comment: You just need to avoid using `0.0.0.0/0` for `AllowedIPs` on the "application server", but only subnet / IPs of the "clients" (and maybe IP of the VPN server).

Comment: Hello. I put in my client the subnet 10.13.13.1/32. But my client ping only the vpn server and internet. Another clients it can't.

Comment: 10.13.13.1/32 is not a subnet address